# PhoneGap sample Hello World start up slowly

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have sample PhoneGap app created by command:

```
phonegap create myApp
```

It is then built using build.phonegapp.com with debugging and hydration set to off.
When the compiled APK is installed into Samsung Galaxy S3, it took 5-7 seconds to start up.

Is it really a typical start up time for PhoneGap app?
If not, how to improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :).

It is due to the splash screen.
Setting splash screen duration to 0 second (in config.xml) removes the delay:

```
<preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="0" />
```